# If our body contained a uniform charge distribution, would we feel ourselves being accelerated in a uniform electric field?

Tags: forces, electric-fields, charge, acceleration

Suppose our body contained a uniform and continuous distribution of electric charge. Let's not care about the actual possibility. Of course this is impossible, but just let's assume that it's somehow attached to our physical body and it stays stationary. Just imagine adding charge to all particles while they all stay in place.

Out in space, we step into a uniform electric field. We will diverge from our geodesic worldline. Will we feel the acceleration? Do the relatively heavy parts of our body show the tendency to lag behind the lower-mass parts (which feels like internal stress? Could we consider it a tidal effect?

Comment: An aside, it's easy to store charge on a human, that's why we sometimes shock things with static electricity. One can also keep in contact with a Van de Graf generator and insulate themselves from the surrounding environment.